# Value parameter annotation vs Type annotation in function in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

when i use Jetpack compose:

```
@Composable
fun parentFuncNeedComp( func:@Composable ()->Unit){
    func()
}
```

I can't move @Composable before func like:

```
@Composable func: ()->Unit
```

It said: **This annotation is not applicable to target 'value parameter'**

And I make a custom annotation named MyAnnotation, and I code a example:

```
@MyAnnotation
fun func1() {

    println("func1")
}
fun func2() {
    println("func2")
}

fun parentFunc(@MyAnnotation func:@MyAnnotation ()->Unit){
    func()
}

fun main() {
    parentFunc(::func2)
    parentFunc(::func1)
}
```

Why both of them work?! And what' s the diff of the @MyAnnotation location?

Comment: @MyAnnotation have added the target : value parameter and type,  my studio don't say wrong in sytax.

Comment: Is what you're asking why you can call `parentFunc(::func2)` even though `func2` isn't annotated with `@MyAnnotation` when you can't do the same using the `@Composable` annotation?

Comment: @NicklasJensen yeah,could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the allowed targets of an annotation in Kotlin using the `@Target` meta-annotation:

```kotlin
@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
annotation class MyAnnotation
```

You can read more about the various meta-annotations for annotations in Kotlin at [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html).

Comment: emmm,, my annotation have added the target both of "value parameter" and "type", there is no red line under my code. I want to know that though my func2 doesn't have the @MyAnnotation why it still work.  And the diff between the annotation's place